# Selenium webdriver 3.0 + java Wait until string entered

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to test my Hotmail account using selenium Webdriver 3.0. I set my account to ask for two way authentication, which means Indeed to enter the last 4 digits of my mobile number and then send a message to me. Then I have to enter that code in order to open my email Account.
It worked good with me when I used implicit, waited for 60 seconds until i receive the code then enter it manually and so the test continues to my email page >> all works fine.

BUT my question is, is there any way to make the test wait until I enter the code rather than waiting for 60s?!
Is that acceptable to enter some things manually while using Selenium webdriver?

Comment: In general, it's not really a good practice to try and test login mechanism which are *not* your SUT (system under test). The reasons to it, as you already encountered, are the different verification mechanism such as CAPTHA / SMS / codes etc which you can't control. In a testing environment, on the other hand, you can mock/inject something more simplified.

Answer (score 1):

> is that acceptable to enter some things manually while using selenium webdriver?

Yes, because this thing is made for stopping robot activity just like **Captcha code** entering the process. So, in this scenario, this is acceptable to enter text manually after reading the text from mail while using selenium.

You can do one thing more if you want to do it automatically, you should implement **mail API** to read the last mail from your provided account in the background and fetch necessary text from the last mail using some **programming stuff** and enter it into textbox using selenium.

> is there any way to make the test wait until I enter the code rather than waiting for 60s?

Yes, to achieve this you need to create your own custom `ExpectedConditions` with `WebDriverWait` which will wait until located text box has value greater or equal 4 character or other suitable condition which you want as below :-

```
//Initialize WebDriverWait first which will wait maximum 60 seconds 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

//Create suitable locator to locate textbox element eg. with xpath locator 
By byObject = By.xpath("enter here textbox xpath");

//This condition will wait until text box has value greater or equal 4 character
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    return (d.findElement(byObject).getAttribute ("value").length() >= 4)
                }
            });
```

Comment: manual intervention in automated tests is acceptable? if there is a dedicated test babysitter perhaps...

Comment: This is depends on situation actually, According to me If you are doing automation there is nothing make sense of manual intervention but If application prevents robot activity on certain steps then what you can do??

Comment: And I have also provided an option to do it automatically by reading last mail using mail api, if you don't want manual...:)